# Is there a way to update extension over composer and bypass memory limit error on Magento2

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

I know there are many posts on related topic of memory limit, i have tried the fixes but they are not working. thought to post a question may be there's some catch.

**Question:** I have *2GB memory* limit defined in php which is the maximum i have available on current hosting. I'm using magento2 and updating extention using composer. in past it worked flawless but now its showing memory error message. Please see the code below. Is there some way i could still make the command run and udpate the extention ? moreover i have tried using `composer_memory_limit=-1` to disable memory limit temporarily but its not working. Please hlep.

```
[techonda@depro13 ]$ php -i | grep memory
memory_limit => 2G => 2G
Collecting memory statistics => No
opcache.memory_consumption => 128 => 128
opcache.preferred_memory_model => no value => no value
opcache.protect_memory => 0 => 0

[techonda@depro13 ]$ composer_memory_limit=-1 composer require  amasty/shopby 2.16.1 --update-with-dependencies
    Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. S
    ee https://getcomposer.org/2
    ./composer.json has been updated
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. S
    ee https://getcomposer.org/2
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    
    Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 528384 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Compose
    r/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php on line 38
    
    Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.[techon
    da@depro13 ]$
```

Comment: As usual: never, never, never run `composer require` on any production system. Run it on your development system which might have more memory, put `composer.lock` under version control, and deploy your application properly

Comment: Also, it might help to use current versions of PHP (at least v7) and Composer, as they offer more performance

Comment: Hi Nico, 
Yes i did use composer require on dev system.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by using following command:

```
php -dmemory_limit=4G /usr/local/bin/composer require amasty/shopby 2.16.1 --update-with-dependencies
```

Comment: Nop. On hosting server. why ? is there something to worry about ?

Comment: As written in the initial comment: run it on your local development machine, such that you can test that your dependencies work before deploying them